# Add class to current link if it matches current url?

Tags: jquery, css, url

I am using this script to highlight current link (add active class):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
$(function() {
  $('nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
});
});
</script>



<li><a href="/category/english/this/?s=<?php
echo '' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["s"]) . '';
?>/">this</a></li>

<li><a href="/category/english/that/?s=<?php
echo '' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["s"]) . '';
?>/">that</a></li>
```

This matches first `/`, for example `/category`, and then highlights everything in menu or any links that start with `/category/...`. I want all to be matched to the third level `1/2/3/whatever`, so if for example I am on url: `/category/english/that/?s=what is this`, I want the links that contain the `/category/english/that/` to be highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you don't need to split `location.pathname`. Try

```js
let pathname = '/category/english/this';
$(function() {
  $('ul a[href^="' + pathname + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="/category/english/this/?s=text">this</a></li>
  <li><a href="/category/english/that/?s=text2/">that</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing happens. Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: nav a

Comment: While it works, on homepage it selects all menu as active. :/

Comment: In the homepage `location.pathname` returns `\ ` only so that it happens. Maybe you can check it with condition